# Building OpenSSH for OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, openssh

I have on OS X 10.5 PowerMac (PowerPC) I use for testing. Apple has abandoned support for it. Others want access to the box for testing, so I need to build and install an updated OpenSSH.

I visited openssh.com and fetched the latest version (7.1) via FTP. The link in the left hand sidebar. There is no download link on the homepage; you kinda have to rummage for it.

Unfortunately, it appears OpenSSH lacks documentation on the process. The is no *`configure`* (so no `configure --help`), there is no *INSTALL*, and there is no topic on it in the [OpenSSH FAQ](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html).

There is a *README* that points me to http://www.openssh.com/portable.html. Unfortunately, that does not provide build instructions. Interestingly, it does talks about both a *`configure`* and *`autoreconf`*  that ***are not*** present in the tarball.

I need to use an updated version of OpenSSL. OpenSSL 1.0.2d has been built and installed in `/usr/local`. I also need to ensure OpenSSH statically links to the alternate OpenSSL so it does not use the downlevel version of OpenSSL 0.9.8 provided by Apple.

How do I build OpenSSH using the updated OpenSSL on OS X? Where do I find the instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I build OpenSSH using the updated OpenSSL on OS X? Where do I find the instructions?

Grawity was correct - I downloaded the wrong OpenSSH. I needed a portable one, and not the one provided at the FTP link. The portable ones are listed at the bottom of [Portable OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/portable.html).

Once you have the portable one, unpack, and then perform the following. The following assumes you have an updated OpenSSL `libcrypto` installed at `/usr/local/ssl/darwin` and an updated Zlib `libz` at `/usr/local`. Adjust them to suite your taste.

***Replace -lz with absolute path to archive***

This is needed to ensure static linking because there is no apparent option for it in `configure`. When the binary is built, `otool -L` will show there are no external Zlib dependencies.

```
$ grep "\-lz" *
configure:{ echo "$as_me:$LINENO: checking for deflate in -lz" >&5
configure:echo $ECHO_N "checking for deflate in -lz... $ECHO_C" >&6; }
configure:LIBS="-lz  $LIBS"
configure:  LIBS="-lz $LIBS"
configure:      LIBS="$LIBS -lz"
configure.ac:       LIBS="$LIBS -lz"
```

Then:

```
$ sed -i "" 's|-lz|/usr/local/lib/libz.a|g' config.h.in configure configure.ac
$
```

***Replace -lcrypto with absolute path to archive***

This is needed to ensure static linking because there is no apparent option for it in `configure`. When the binary is built, `otool -L` will show there are no external OpenSSL dependencies.

```
$ grep "\-lcrypto" *
configure:  LIBS="-lcrypto $LIBS"
configure.ac:   LIBS="-lcrypto $LIBS"
```

Then:

```
$ sed -i "" 's|-lcrypto|/usr/local/ssl/darwin/lib/libcrypto.a|g' configure configure.ac
$
```

In the above, I use `/usr/local/ssl/darwin` as `--openssldir` when building the OpenSSL library. Its usually just `/usr/local/ssl`. Adjust it as necessary.

***Configure OpenSSH***

Configure OpenSSH with the needed paths. You might need to include a OS X library, too.

If `find /usr/lib/ -name libsandbox*` returns `libsandbox.dylib`, then you need to include `--with-libs="-lsandbox`. Its missing on OS X 10.5, but its present on OS X 10.8. If the library is present but `--with-libs` is omitted, then it will result in an error similar to ***`riemann.local sshd[15748]: fatal: ssh_sandbox_child: sandbox_init: dlopen(/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib, 261): image not found [preauth]`***.

```
$ ./configure --without-ssh1 --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl/darwin --with-zlib=/usr/local \
  --with-libs="-lsandbox" --prefix=/usr/local
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
...

OpenSSH has been configured with the following options:
                     User binaries: /usr/local/bin
                   System binaries: /usr/local/sbin
               Configuration files: /usr/local/etc
...

Host: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0
Compiler: gcc
Compiler flags: -g -O2 -Qunused-arguments -Wunknown-warning-option -Wall -Wpointer-arith 
    -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess
    -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-unused-result -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
    -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all -fPIE 
Preprocessor flags: -I/usr/local/ssl/darwin/include -I/usr/local/include 
Linker flags: -L/usr/local/ssl/darwin/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -fstack-protector-all -pie
Libraries: /usr/local/ssl/darwin/lib/libcrypto.a /usr/local/lib/libz.a -lsandbox -lresolv
```

You might need `--with-pam` to get password authentication working. I was not concerned with the feature, so I did not add the configuration option.

***Build and Install OpenSSH***

The `-fwrapv` is somewhat troubling when seen in high integrity software. That usually means there's an [illegal C program with undefined behavior](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120) afoot. The developers have not fixed it, so they use [`-fwrapv` as a band-aide](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120).

```
$ make
conffile=`echo sshd_config.out | sed 's/.out$//'`; \
...

gcc -g -O2 -Qunused-arguments -Wunknown-warning-option -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized
  -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-pointer-sign
  -Wno-unused-result -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset
  -fstack-protector-all -fPIE  -I. -I.. -I. -I./.. -I/usr/local/ssl/darwin/include
-I/usr/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c arc4random.c
gcc -g -O2 -Qunused-arguments -Wunknown-warning-option -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized
  -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-pointer-sign
  -Wno-unused-result -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset
  -fstack-protector-all -fPIE  -I. -I.. -I. -I./.. -I/usr/local/ssl/darwin/include
  -I/usr/local/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c bsd-asprintf.c
...
```

External dependencies (or lack thereof) can be verified with:

```
$ otool -L ./sshd 
./sshd:
    /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Unfortunately, there is no `make check` or `make test` targets, so there's no apparent way to test the software before installing it.

```
$ sudo make install
...

Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key.
Your public key has been saved in /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:u/xQ6haFqxjG0fBgSMt0W58N8zmhu+NmyQxNMkMcwPc root@riemann.home.dmz
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
| .ooooo.o .      |
| o.o=o+. B o     |
|  o..B .+.=      |
|    . * E...     |
|   . . *So.      |
|    + . +=       |
|   . o =*o       |
|    . .+B+       |
|       +=..      |
+----[SHA256]-----+
...
```

***Create a Plist for the new SSH binary***

The following uses the existing `ssh.plist`, removes the Apple wrapper script, and changes the port number. Copy it to `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-7.1.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.openssh.sshd.7-1</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd</string>
        <string>-i</string>
        <string>-e</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>/usr/local/etc/sshd_config</string>
        <string>-o</string>
        <string>PidFile=/var/run/sshd-7.1.pid</string>
    </array>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
            <key>Listeners</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>SockServiceName</key>
                    <string>1522</string>
            </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/sshd-7.1.log</string>
    <key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
    <string>system.preferences</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There's a few things going on in the plist:

- the service label was changed to `com.openssh.sshd.7-1` to avoid colliding with Apple's `com.openssh.sshd`
- the PID file was changed to `var/run/sshd-7.1.pid` to avoid colliding with Apple's `var/run/sshd.pid`
- the program's absolute path was included in `ProgramArguments` due to a ***`sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path`*** while servicing client connections
- `sshd_config` is called out specifically to avoid open questions and confusion. But its used by default
- the use of the -`i` option even though its an [`inetd(8)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/inetd.8?query=inetd&sec=8) option. According to [sshd and -i option on OS X](https://superuser.com/q/961390), it should be used

***Start the new SSH service***

Use launchd to start the service. Notice the use of `-w` to avoid the *"nothing found to load"* error message because the service is disabled.

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-7.1.plist
```

Finally, verify the new SSH server is operating:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 1522
tcp6       0      0  *.1522                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.1522                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

> I visited openssh.com and fetched the latest version (7.1) via FTP.

The link under "For OpenBSD: FTP / HTTP" is, as the name says, **for OpenBSD only**. It needs to be built using the OpenBSD 'Ports' tools.

Since you're running OS X, not OpenBSD, you'll have to download it from "For other OSs → Others…". (Scroll down to the "Download" section.) The official OpenSSH-portable **7.1p1** tarball definitely has both a `configure` script and an `INSTALL` document.

Static linking shouldn't be necessary; OS X binaries *can* depend on libraries at an absolute path. (I think that might even be the default?)

> There is no download link on the homepage; you kinda have to rummage for it.

I agree that the website is sort of stuck in 1990's, but I wouldn't say two clicks instead of one count as rummaging... If it had a download page, it would just contain the same OS links which are *already* in the sidebar, wouldn't it?

> Where do I find the instructions?

Take a look at Homebrew, especially its [openssh formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/openssh.rb). Also:

- http://www.dctrwatson.com/2013/07/how-to-update-openssh-on-mac-os-x/
- https://mochtu.de/2015/01/07/updating-openssh-on-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite/

Comment: Thanks Grawity. That site is a confusing mess... I downloaded it via FTP because there was no explicit *Download* link, and it lacked a download under the *Mac OS X* link. Also, I'm not using Homebrew or Macports. I'm trying to minimize maintenance since this box exists for testing PowerPC ports of software.

Comment: Thanks again Grawity. It was much more than a simple `./configure ... && make`, but I think we got it. I don't like the `sshd.c` hack, but I think its the best/easiest until the OpenSSH dev's fix the problem. Thanks for the help.