# sshd and -i option on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, ssh

According to the man page on [`sshd(8)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd&sec=8):

```
 -i      Specifies that sshd is being run from inetd(8).  sshd is normally
         not run from inetd because it needs to generate the server key
         before it can respond to the client, and this may take tens of
         seconds.  Clients would have to wait too long if the key was
         regenerated every time.  However, with small key sizes (e.g. 512)
         using sshd from inetd may be feasible.
```

I'm a bit confused as to what to do with the option. On the Mac I am working on, the Apple Launchd `ssh.plist` includes the option. But Apple does not use `inetd(8)` *and* the keys already exist.

Should I be using the `-i` option on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files on disk are the permanent *host* keys, but the manual is talking about the temporary *key exchange* keys, which are used to achieve [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).

Note that the message is talking specifically about SSHv1, which used temporary RSA keypairs regenerated on startup and every hour. Modern systems do not use SSHv1 anymore so the warning is no longer relevant.

(SSHv2 uses [DH key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) instead, which uses a new key for each exchange, but generating the DH keypairs is much faster, along with [various other advantages](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/35471/4258).)

---

Yes, you should still use the option. It is a general option for the *mechanism* of launching a network server in the way that inetd introduced and that launchd uses.

(The mechanism, sometimes called "socket activation", can be implemented on any Unix-like system, and even Windows with some difficulties. For example, Linux 'systemd' is often also configured to start sshd with "-i".)

Comment: Oh, I see. regarding the keys, the man page is talking about ephemeral keys. Maybe the man page should explicitly state that. Regarding the launch options, may the man page should just say a "launch daemon" rather than specifically calling out `inetd` (at the exclusion of all other launch daemons).