# How to instruct `sshd` to use its absolute path when forking?

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, openssh

I have an an older PowerMac G5 with a PowerPC that needs modern SSH access. There is no vendor support. I updated OpenSSL and OpenSSH, and installed them in `/usr/local`. The updated `sshd` is located at `/usr/local/sbin/sshd` and listens on port 1522.

Connections to the server are being refused, and the client displays ***`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`***. I enabled `-d` logging at the server, and its writing ***`/var/log/sshd.log:sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path`*** to `stderr`.

Here's the full transcript on a test connection:

```
$ grep -I -R sshd /var/log 2>/dev/null
/var/log/appfirewall.log:Aug 23 13:15:22 riemann.local socketfilterfw[122] <Info>: sshd is listening from 0.0.0.0:1522 proto=6
/var/log/appfirewall.log:Aug 23 13:15:22 riemann.local socketfilterfw[122] <Info>: sshd is listening from :::1522 proto=6
/var/log/sshd.log:Aug 23 13:16:43 riemann.local launchproxy[362] <Info>: /usr/local/sbin/sshd: Connection from: 127.0.0.1 on port: 49157
/var/log/sshd.log:sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path
```

When I configured OpenSSH at build time, I don't recall an option related to fork behavior. `./configure --help | egrep "(fork|re-exec)"` returns nothing. I configured with `./configure --without-ssh1 --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl/darwin --with-zlib=/usr/local --prefix=/usr/local`.

How do I tell `sshd` to use its absolute path (`/usr/local/sbin/sshd`) when forking?

---

***EDIT***. It appears the error message ***`sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path`*** is caused by the following in `sshd.c`. It is present near line 1625:

```
if (!test_flag && (rexec_flag && (av[0] == NULL || *av[0] != '/')))
    fatal("sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path");
```

Changing the code to print `av[0]` shows there is no executable or path. The new message (because of the changes below) includes ***`(re-exec with "-i -d")`***.

```
if (!test_flag && (rexec_flag && (av[0] == NULL || *av[0] != '/')))
    fatal("sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path (re-exec with \"%s\")", (av[0] ? av[0] : "<NULL>"));
```

Unfortunately, changing the plist to:

```
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd -i -d</string>
    </array>
```

Results in the following (notice `sshd.c` still stripped the absolute path I entered at `argv[0]`):

```
$ sudo grep 'sshd' /var/log/* 2>/dev/null
/var/log/system.log:Aug 23 15:51:22 riemann.local sshd -i -d[1243]: error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
/var/log/system.log:Aug 23 15:51:22 riemann.local sshd -i -d[1243]: error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
/var/log/system.log:Aug 23 15:51:22 riemann.local sshd -i -d[1243]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
```

---

I don't know how/what Launchd uses to start the daemon at startup, but the plist is shown below. Startup is fine; the problem occurs when a client connects during the fork/exec.

I can stop it once its started with `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-7.1.plist`. I can then restart it with `sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-7.1.plist`.

---

```
$ cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh-7.1.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.openssh.sshd-v7.1</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>-i -d</string>
    </array>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
            <key>Listeners</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>SockServiceName</key>
                    <string>1522</string>
            </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/sshd.log</string>
    <key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
    <string>system.preferences</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Tell me how do you start `sshd`. It requires absolute path for re-exec, which means, that you can't start is directly as `sshd`, but you need to provide full path, like `/usr/local/sbin/sshd`. This is all the magic

Comment: @Jakuje - I added additional information related to Launchd. I'm not quite sure how Launchd starts it, but I think its OK because it actually starts. The problem seems to arise in the fork/exec when a client connects.

Comment: if `sshd` would be started with relative path, it should reject even to start from my experience ...

Comment: Yes, if you remove `-d` switch, it should not complain about the path anymore, since it will exchange reexec by fork (re-exec is only in debug more).

Comment: @Jakuje  - Using just `-i` results in the original problem. Do you have a Mac to test on? Here are the instructions I used: [Building OpenSSH for OS X?](http://superuser.com/a/961422/173513). I transcribed the steps I used to help others, but it might just help me :)

Comment: No. I don't have Mac. But this discussion is getting long. Is it now working or is there still some problem or question?

Comment: @Jakuje  - I managed to get clear the re-exec problem (answer below). I'll open a new question on the `dlopen` failure I am now experiencing if Google does not provide any resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the plist file copied based on the information provided in [a Server Fault question/answer](https://serverfault.com/q/18761/145545). The plist needs to explicitly callout `usr/local/sbin/sshd` as a `ProgramArguments`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.openssh.sshd.7-1</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/sbin/sshd</string>
        <string>-i</string>
    </array>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
            <key>Listeners</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>SockServiceName</key>
                    <string>1522</string>
            </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
    <key>SHAuthorizationRight</key>
    <string>system.preferences</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```