# Use SSH server at /usr/local/sbin/sshd?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, openssh

I'm working on a [MIPSEL ci20 dev-board](http://creatordev.io/ci20). It runs Debian 7 so its no longer receiving security updates. Debian 8 is in beta and it appears to be suffering some memory issues, so I don't want to risk an upgrade at this point in time.

I've updated OpenSSL to 1.0.2h (from 1.0.1e) and OpenSSH to 7.3 (from 6.0). I also used static linking for OpenSSH with OpenSSL to avoid the problems it was having with library version checks during configure.

I'm having trouble finding information on instructing Debian to use the local OpenSSH. The information I have found starts with `apt-get install openssh-server`. For example, the Debian wiki and [Installation of the server](http://wiki.debian.org/SSH#Installation_of_the_server) assumes a Debian provided OpenSSH.

Grepping in `/etc` for `sshd` shows a lot of hard coded paths, like:

```
$ sudo grep -R 'sshd' /etc 2>/dev/null
...
/etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server:if [ ! -e /usr/sbin/sshd ]; then
/etc/init.d/ssh:test -x /usr/sbin/sshd || exit 0
/etc/init.d/ssh: if start-stop-daemon ... --exec /usr/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
...
```

How do I tell Debian to use the OpenSSH server at `/usr/local/sbin/sshd`?

Comment: probably you will have to modify or create a new init scripts to use `/usr/local/sbin/sshd` or overwrite the old sshd with your one.

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje. I'm thinking I should start the local SSH server on a different port and test it. Once the local SSH is OK, remove the distro OpenSSH and create a softlink from `/usr/sbin/sshd` to `/usr/local/sbin/sshd`. Regarding *new init scripts*, I already had this open: [Making scripts run at boot time with Debian](http://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian) from the admin guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a local OpenSSH server was possible, including a complete removal of the distro OpenSSH server. There were four steps.

***Build and Install OpenSSH server***

The first step is to build a version of OpenSSH which suits your taste. An example is given for OS X at [Building OpenSSH for OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/961349). It mostly applies to Linux as well, and uses static linking (see the `sed`) to avoid configuration and dynamic linking problems.

***Remove distro OpenSSH server***

The second step is to perform a `apt-get remove --purge openssh-server`. The `--purge` attempted to ensure no cross pollination.

If desired, backup the current `sshd_config` to use for future reference. Be aware OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenSSH 7.3 offer things their predecessors don't, like curve25519.

***Create an unprivileged user***

The third step is to create an unprivileged user for privilege separation. Its needed because the previous unprivileged user account was purged. For this step see `README.privsep`:

```
# mkdir /var/empty
# chown root:sys /var/empty
# chmod 755 /var/empty
# groupadd sshd
# useradd -g sshd -c 'sshd privsep' -d /var/empty -s /bin/false sshd
```

***Add a startup script for sshd-local***

For this step, see [Making scripts run at boot time with Debian](https://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian) from the admin manual. The script below was based on Debian's SSH startup script. The name was changed to ***`sshd-local`*** to avoid collisions. It also adds `-f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config` to ensure the correct config file is used.

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     sshd-local
# Required-Start:   $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     
# Short-Description:    Local OpenBSD Secure Shell server
### END INIT INFO

set -e

# /etc/init.d/ssh-local: start and stop the local OpenBSD secure shell daemon

test -x /usr/local/sbin/sshd || exit 0
( /usr/local/sbin/sshd -\? 2>&1 | grep -q OpenSSH ) 2>/dev/null || exit 0

umask 022

if test -f /etc/default/ssh; then
    . /etc/default/ssh
fi

if test -f /lib/lsb/init-functions; then
    . /lib/lsb/init-functions
fi

if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    SSHD_OPTS="$SSHD_OPTS -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config $2"
fi

# Are we running from init?
run_by_init() {
    ([ "$previous" ] && [ "$runlevel" ]) || [ "$runlevel" = S ]
}

check_for_no_start() {
    # forget it if we're trying to start, and /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run exists
    if [ -e /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run ]; then 
    if [ "$1" = log_end_msg ]; then
        log_end_msg 0 || true
    fi
    if ! run_by_init; then
        log_action_msg "Local OpenBSD Secure Shell server not in use (/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run)" || true
    fi
    exit 0
    fi
}

check_dev_null() {
    if [ ! -c /dev/null ]; then
    if [ "$1" = log_end_msg ]; then
        log_end_msg 1 || true
    fi
    if ! run_by_init; then
        log_action_msg "/dev/null is not a character device!" || true
    fi
    exit 1
    fi
}

check_privsep_dir() {
    # Create the PrivSep empty dir if necessary
    if [ ! -d /var/run/sshd-local ]; then
    mkdir /var/run/sshd-local
    chmod 0755 /var/run/sshd-local
    fi
}

check_config() {
    if [ ! -e /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run ]; then
    /usr/local/sbin/sshd $SSHD_OPTS -t || exit 1
    fi
}

export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

case "$1" in
  start)
    check_privsep_dir
    check_for_no_start
    check_dev_null
    log_daemon_msg "Starting local OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd-local.pid --exec /usr/local/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
        log_end_msg 0 || true
    else
        log_end_msg 1 || true
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping local OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd-local.pid; then
        log_end_msg 0 || true
    else
        log_end_msg 1 || true
    fi
    ;;

  reload|force-reload)
    check_for_no_start
    check_config
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading local OpenBSD Secure Shell server's configuration" "sshd" || true
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 1 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd-local.pid --exec /usr/local/sbin/sshd; then
        log_end_msg 0 || true
    else
        log_end_msg 1 || true
    fi
    ;;

  restart)
    check_privsep_dir
    check_config
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting local OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry 30 --pidfile /var/run/sshd-local.pid
    check_for_no_start log_end_msg
    check_dev_null log_end_msg
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd-local.pid --exec /usr/local/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
        log_end_msg 0 || true
    else
        log_end_msg 1 || true
    fi
    ;;

  try-restart)
    check_privsep_dir
    check_config
    log_daemon_msg "Restarting local OpenBSD Secure Shell server" "sshd" || true
    RET=0
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry 30 --pidfile /var/run/sshd-local.pid || RET="$?"
    case $RET in
        0)
        # old daemon stopped
        check_for_no_start log_end_msg
        check_dev_null log_end_msg
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/sshd-local.pid --exec /usr/local/sbin/sshd -- $SSHD_OPTS; then
            log_end_msg 0 || true
        else
            log_end_msg 1 || true
        fi
        ;;
        1)
        # daemon not running
        log_progress_msg "(not running)" || true
        log_end_msg 0 || true
        ;;
        *)
        # failed to stop
        log_progress_msg "(failed to stop)" || true
        log_end_msg 1 || true
        ;;
    esac
    ;;

  status)
    status_of_proc -p /var/run/sshd-local.pid /usr/local/sbin/sshd sshd && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;

  *)
    log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/ssh-local {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|try-restart|status}" || true
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```